# Filter information in python dictionaries dynamically

Tags: json, python-3.x

## Filter information in python dictionaries dynamically

Hello first of all say that I am understanding how to filter information in python dictionaries from a JSON to later write them in a JSON file for it I take a regular workflow and I am leaving that we do not always know exactly what we must iterate to illustrate a simple but real life example.

### The work flow

- Decode JSON
- Treat and process the data (convert it into information)
- Encode JSON And write them

### The example

for this I am using the apin of [CoinMarketCap](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/) and this is the data structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "website_slug": "bitcoin",
      "rank": 1,
      "circulating_supply": 17168112.0,
      "total_supply": 17168112.0,
      "max_supply": 21000000.0,
      "quotes": {
          "USD": {
          "price": 8159.91,
          "volume_24h": 6805930000.0,
          "market_cap": 140090248790.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -0.65,
          "percent_change_24h": 5.84,
          "percent_change_7d": 18.14
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1532445803
    },
    "1027": {
      "id": 1027,
      "name": "Ethereum",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "website_slug": "ethereum",
      "rank": 2,
      "circulating_supply": 100891486.0,
      "total_supply": 100891486.0,
      "max_supply": null,
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 472.418,
          "volume_24h": 2187530000.0,
          "market_cap": 47662953974.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -1.42,
          "percent_change_24h": 2.14,
          "percent_change_7d": -1.83
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1532445813
    },
    "52": {
      "id": 52,
      "name": "XRP",
      "symbol": "XRP",
      "website_slug": "ripple",
      "rank": 3,
      "circulating_supply": 39315683476.0,
      "total_supply": 99991900487.0,
      "max_supply": 100000000000.0,
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 0.458599,
          "volume_24h": 305718000.0,
          "market_cap": 18030133126.0,
          "percent_change_1h": -1.22,
          "percent_change_24h": 1.69,
          "percent_change_7d": -5.25
        }
      },
      "last_updated": 1532445797
    },
  "metadata": {
    "timestamp": 1532445415,
    "num_cryptocurrencies": 1664,
    "error": null
  }
}
```

As you can see are nested dictionaries and there comes a point where you can not iterate explicitly, we must do it dynamically otherwise we should know the id of the crypto currency.

We start the exploration of the dictionaries:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/")
data = json.loads(response.text)


def keep(data):
    for i in data['data'].key():
        print(i)


keep(data)
```

As you can see this is the complex part to iterate.

I managed to get rid of the complex part to get the Top10 of cryptocurrencies:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/")
data = json.loads(response.text)


def keep(data):
    for i in data['data'].values():
    if i['rank'] <= 10:
        print(json.dumps(i, indent=4))


keep(data)
```

But I can not write it to a JSON file, I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "I cannot mean"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you want to do:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/")
data = json.loads(response.text)

finallist=[]
def keep(data):
    for i in data['data'].values():
        if i['rank'] <= 10:
            finallist.append(i)


keep(data) 
#jsondata = json.dumps(finallist)
with open('data1sk.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(finallist, outfile)
```

This should give your desired result, but you didn't tell, what was not working in your case clearly. However, this is the solution you may try.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. This is what I wanted to do. I would like to know if there is any way to get it smarter and which is more efficient in performance.

Comment: Since it's a small data, this should be fine. I think. However if it was large enough, you could get it done using dataframe. Well depends on the size of data that you want to recieve. If however if my answer helped you could you please upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: Yes, he definitely helped me with his answer.